# How to format date fields using select query with Oracle

Tags: oracle, node-red

[image: click here==>Payload Image]

I am new to node red.

I am storing into the Oracle db in this date format `dd-mm-yy hh:mi:ss.ff PM` but I am getting a payload using a select query in this format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.000Z` but while retrieving data from Oracle db I want to print this format   `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` in my payload,  how to write select query so that I can print the same date format,whatever stored in Oracle db

Comment: Please edit the question to include the queries you have already tried.

Comment: It's important to understand, that the dates (as well as timestamps) are not stored in any text format in Oracle DB. It uses its own internal representation. You can turn it to a specifically formatted text explicitly (i.e. by type conversion expression or function, like `TO_CHAR`) or it can be turned to text implicitly (e.g. by client libraries, usually based on some regional settings, e.g. NLS settings of the Oracle client, or system regional settings, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch a date value, it is stringified according to the NLS settings of your client. Looking at the same data with two different clients, you might *see* two different representations... of the same date.

If you want to choose the display format of a date, use Oracle function TO_CHAR in your query. It accepts a date and a format spec, and returns a string :

```
TO_CHAR(my_date_column, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

It is also possible to change the default date format for the life time of your session, like :

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
```

NB : if you are dealing with timestamps or timestamps with time zone, you need `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`.